# What does "__declspec(dllexport)" do?

Tags: visual-studio

Is this a Visual Studio defined function or a Windows defined function? What will it do when called?
Can somebody provide me with a link with details about this function?

Answer (score 2):

When you create a DLL, by default, any functions defined within the DLL are only callable from that same **DLL**. You cannot call that function from an executable or a different DLL.

If you want your a function to be called from outside the DLL, you need to **export** it by adding `__declspec(dllexport)`. One way to think about it is that `__declspec(dllexport)` marks a function as being part of a DLL's public interface.

You could read about them in [msdn.microsoft.com](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a90k134d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Basically it is just a MSVC-specific macro that tells the compiler to export that function into a DLL. For more information see the MSDN page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/3y1sfaz2%28v=vs.80%29.aspx